# Get the stack trace of exception in Rhino

Tags: rhino

We have an app that allows to enter a scripts. These scripts can be in multiple files, so when there is an exception we want to be able to show a stack trace to the app admin so he can diagnose the issue.

Is there there a way to extract the stack trace from a Rhino exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in order to get a good stack trace, you need to be very careful when evaluating scripts in your scope. I've seen that this is overlooked by many developers where they always send the same params for `sourceName` and `lineno`, like:

```
ctx.evaluateString(scriptScope, script, "script", 0, null);
```

So in the 3rd and 4th params you have to send the file name of something that will help the developer identify the script. Then, the line number should be correct, in case you concatenate scripts.

So, once you evaluate all the scripts in your context correctly, you can be able to get a useful stack track. So just catch the exception and process the info in the stack trace:

```
try {
  // execute script
} catch (RhinoException re) {
  StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = re.getStackTrace();
  if (stackTrace != null) {
    for (StackTraceElement stackElement : stackTrace) {
      // stackElement.getFileName();
      // stackElement.getLineNumber();
    }
  }
}
```